# Camera face detection

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, face-recognition

I'm about to make an app, I need to know if the person is running using the the front camera, so I need to know where are their eyes and the mouth.

The problem is that I've been searching but I don't find anything like that on Titanium just for pictures and I have to do it in real time.

is this possible on Titanium?, or I have to do it native?

sorry for my bad english

Update:
The app is for IOS and Android

Comment: I would suggest to use the emulators to test.  If you're creating a mobile apps for Android, check the Emulator in Android Studio.  If it's a Web App, check the emulators on Chrome/Firefox/Internet Explorer :).  Would you like to give more information?

Comment: sorry, i forget, the app is for iOS and Android

Comment: I've never used Mac computers to program.  But if you're using Android Studio, you can use the Emulators to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks, but i dont want to do that, i want to be able to detect eyes and mouth using the front camera, the problem is that i dont find i how to do that

Comment: As far as iOS is concerned, you can do it with a `CIDetector` - and it's pretty easy too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS you can use the following Titanium module which wraps the `CIDetector` framework:

http://gitt.io/component/by.farwayer.facerecognizer